# Is it possible to add older version com.android.support:appcompat-v7 in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

How can I add the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` for android version 7.
Android studio forces me to set the compile version to `22.1.1`,
but when the project doesn't compile.

I have to set the compile version and the target version to 7,
cause otherwise some functionality doesn't work.

My `build-gradle` look like this:

```
apply plugin: `'com.android.application'`

android {
    compileSdkVersion 7
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ella.pulltorefreshexample"
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 7
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: there is no such thing as appcompat for version 7.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I add the com.android.support:appcompat-v7 for android version 7

There was no version 7. The oldest is 18.0.0, and the 21+ editions are significantly different than the ones prior to that.

> I have to set the compile version and the target version to 7, cause otherwise some functionality doesn't work.

Then you need to fix the functionality in your app (so that you can use a higher `compileSdkVersion` and a realistic `targetSdkVersion`), or not use `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: How can I ***not use `appcompat-v7`***? Like how can I downgrade?

Comment: @OlowookereEmmanuel: Remove `appcompat-v7` from the project (e.g., `app/build.gradle`). Change your activities to inherit from `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`. Also change them to use a theme other than `Theme.AppCompat` (e.g., `Theme.Holo`, `Theme.Material`). If you have menu resources, change the `app:`-prefixed attributes to `android:`. There are probably some additional changes as well, but that should get you most of the way there.